Ansible evaluate list of tab separated strings
I am running a command, after which stdout is captured in a variable. The command output lists values separated by tabs. So I have something like
var.stdout_lines: [
  "a1\tb1\tc1",
  "a2\tb2\tc2",
  "a3\tb3\tc3"
]

For further processing I'd like to split these lines into lists such as
[
  [a1, b1, c1],
  [a2, b2, c2],
  [a3, b3, c3]
]

How can I achieve that?

Split the items
result: "{{ out.stdout_lines | map('split') }}"




Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    out:
      stdout_lines: [
        "a1\tb1\tc1",
        "a2\tb2\tc2",
        "a3\tb3\tc3"]

    result: "{{ out.stdout_lines | map('split') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines

    - debug:
        var: result



Use Python virtual environment. For example, in Ubuntu

(env) > cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=23.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=mantic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 23.10"

(env) > python3 -m pip list | grep ansible
ansible                   9.5.1
ansible-compat            4.1.11
ansible-core              2.16.6
ansible-lint              24.2.2
ansible-runner            2.3.6



Good idea. I did not think of 'map'. Yet I am running into another issue and thus need time to verify: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870792/jinja2-exceptions-templateruntimeerror-no-filter-named-split

Run it in Python virtual environment and install the latest version of Ansible. This works the same way in Ubuntu.

Upgraded Ansible, and your solution works like a dream!
